# SQL Date Range Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a TABLE with date ranges bound by two fields (Start and End):

```
ID  |  START      |  END
1      2010-01-01    2010-07-01
2      2011-01-01    2011-07-01
3      2012-01-01    2013-07-01
4      2013-01-01    2013-07-01
5      2009-01-01    2013-07-01
```

I could get a rough estimate of the number of 'months' represented by all ranges by a query like:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(dy, Start, End) / 30) as Total_Months
FROM TABLE
```

What I would rather like to do is to query how many months (or days) are represented by all ranges within a given period of time.

So If I asked how many months are represented from the time period `[2013-01-01 - 2013-07-01]` in the example above, it would say `18` (6 from each of rows 3, 4 and 5).

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you want to count months? E.g., is `2013-01-14 - 2013-02-13` a month? Are `2013-01-31 - 2013-03-01` two months? Or can we assume that both `START` and `END` contain the 1st of each month?

Comment: I would like to count a month as Month = 30 days.

Comment: I want the results for the entire table, as in my SUM(DATEDIFF) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** You can do it like this

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(dy, 
                    CASE WHEN '2013-01-01' > Start THEN '2013-01-01' ELSE Start END,
                    CASE WHEN '2013-07-01' < [End] THEN '2013-07-01' ELSE [End] END) / 30) Total_Months
  FROM Table1
 WHERE '2013-01-01' BETWEEN Start AND [End]
   AND '2013-07-01' BETWEEN Start AND [End]
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL_MONTHS |
----------------
|           18 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/699df/8)** demo

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do the trick either.  I think the example I gave, with the 5 rows, the range, and the answer (18 months) describes my question pretty well.  In the SQLFiddle demo you provide, the total months = 24.

Comment: Sorry I misread your requirements at first. Please see the updated answer and sqlfiddle example.

Comment: I think the case may be switched for the end date (which wouldn't make a difference in my example), but this is otherwise perfect thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(dy, Start, End) / 30) as Total_Months
WHERE Start >= '2013-01-01' AND End <= '2013-07-01'
FROM TABLE
```

Or to make it parameterized:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(dy, Start, End) / 30) as Total_Months
WHERE Start >= @startDate AND End <= @endDate
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will tell me the total number of months in ranges which overlap with a given period, but I want to exclude the parts of ranges which do not fall within the selected time period.